# How to replace the maximum value in each row in a dataframe by an individual value

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

Today I failed in doing a simple task:

I want to replace the maximum value in each row of a data frame with a specific individual value that I have computed before. I did not know how I could tell

```
DF <- structure(list(age_n = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), female_noe_n = c(0.674555812063115, 
0.681331945419623, 0.632659475334461, 0.649517172953091, 0.64918662986253, 
0.667531771388686), male_noe_n = c(0.734797290317925, 0.742565052946117, 
0.715791062610646, 0.729425965096302, 0.710171830071103, 0.734962561863205
), female_v_n = c(0.745209397670608, 0.86387436718214, 0.915191181991792, 
1.01146185711779, 1.04658206048994, 1.11211222819373), male_v_n = c(0.783635031948367, 
0.860486300503885, 0.909571949452249, 0.995595788770845, 1.03071599214299, 
1.12996155508404)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

ID <- apply(DF, 1, function(x) which.max(x))

# Now I need to overwrite the rowwise maximum by ceiling 
overwrite_value <- 
  sapply(1:nrow(DF), function(x)
    DF[x,ID[[x]]] %>% ceiling())
```

I guess there are simple solutions and I am stuck in something too complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)

individual_value <- 5

DF %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate( x = max(c_across(2:5))) %>% 
  mutate(across(2:5, ~case_when(. == x ~ individual_value,
                                TRUE ~ .)), .keep="unused"
         )
```

```
  age_n female_noe_n male_noe_n female_v_n male_v_n
  <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1     2        0.675      0.735      0.745    5    
2     3        0.681      0.743      5        0.860
3     3        0.633      0.716      5        0.910
4     3        0.650      0.729      5        0.996
5     3        0.649      0.710      5        1.03 
6     3        0.668      0.735      1.11     5
```

Comment: I need to overwrite rowwise means by a vector of values, not just one single value.

Comment: This command worked well. I just modified one thing: 

DF %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate( x = max(c_across(2:5))) %>% 
  mutate(across(2:5, ~ case_when(. == x ~ ceiling(x),
                                TRUE ~ .)), .keep="unused"
  )

Instead of individual value I used ceiling(x)

Comment: I just wonder if there is a shorter way? From this code I understand, that we generate a new variable x that contains the row-wise maximum value and then through comparison we replace the value. Can't we skip the step with the new variable?

Comment: You are right. You can do: `DF %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(2:5, ~case_when(. == max(c_across(2:5)) ~ individual_value,
                                TRUE ~ .)), .keep="unused"
  )`! But this one is more difficult to read, I think! :-)

Comment: Thanks. That's true - it think as intermediate step it is very useful. But later on, I would replace it :) Thanks, I still need to learn a lot about dpylr commands. They're damn useful.

Answer (score 2):

With row/column indexing it will be more efficient i.e. get the column index per row for the `max` value with `max.col`, `cbind` with the row sequence to return a matrix of row/column index, extract the value and assign (based on the OP's description - `I want to replace the maximum value in each row of a data frame with a specific individual value that I have computed before`)

```
m1 <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(DF)), max.col(DF[-1]))
DF[-1][m1] <- 5
```

-output

```
> DF
  age_n female_noe_n male_noe_n female_v_n  male_v_n
1     2    0.6745558  0.7347973  0.7452094 5.0000000
2     3    0.6813319  0.7425651  5.0000000 0.8604863
3     3    0.6326595  0.7157911  5.0000000 0.9095719
4     3    0.6495172  0.7294260  5.0000000 0.9955958
5     3    0.6491866  0.7101718  5.0000000 1.0307160
6     3    0.6675318  0.7349626  1.1121122 5.0000000
```

NOTE: If it is a vector of values to replace i.e. one element for each row, just assign it to that vector

```
DF[-1][m1] <- c(5, 10, 5, 15, 20, 5)
```

Comment: This is not the solution I need. But was the better way as TarJae's.

Comment: But I like the max.col command and I reused it in my following command and got what I needed. Thanks

Comment: new_DF <- apply(DF[-1],1, function(x) ifelse(max(x)==x, max.col(x),x))
View(t(new_DF))

Comment: But for whatever reason it transposed the table after my apply command.

Comment: `max.col` gives the index of max value per row.  It is combined with the row index to extract the value and that is used to get the ceiling of that.  Your code suggests that

Comment: @NadiineElNino if you need to overwrite with `5`, just change it to `DF[m1] <- 5`

Comment: @NadiineElNino with `apply` and `MARGIN = 1`, you need to transpose the output with `t`

Comment: Ah now I see what I did wrong- I know it is the index! But I need to overwrite rowise maximum values by a its ceiling.

Comment: new_DF <- apply(DF[-1],1, function(x) ifelse(max(x)==x, ceiling(x),x))
View(t(new_DF))

Comment: I set the margin to 1 and I still need to transpose it

Comment: which.max and max.col are not giving the same result? Thanks I just read the manual it doing different things. I was not aware of that.